# String comparision return false for identical strings

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

below is the code I used to compare df ouptut against a string. Can anybody tell me why it always returns false?

```
bash-3.00$ a=$(df -n dir1)
bash-3.00$ b="/opt               : ufs"
bash-3.00$ echo "$a"
/opt               : ufs
bash-3.00$ echo "$b"
/opt               : ufs
bash-3.00$ [[ "$a" = "$b" ]]
bash-3.00$ echo $?
1
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$ [[ "$a" == "$b" ]]
bash-3.00$ echo $?
1
```

Thanks,

Comment: You might have tabs in the output of df.  You can check by e.g. `df -n dir1 | grep opt > /tmp/df.out` and then examining the contents carefully in an editor.

Comment: What happens if you try the following:

#/bin/bash

a="/opt"
b="/opt"

[ "$a" = "$b" ]
echo $?

Comment: Let's see if the df is adding junk into variable, which is causing a comparison issue.

Comment: You can pipe the contents of each variable through `od` or `hexdump` to see exactly what each variable contains, but I suspect it is some form of differing whitespace that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following analogous sequence worked for me:

```
x=$(df -n /dev | grep dev)
y="devfs             226  226         0   100%    /dev"
[[ $x == $y ]]
echo $?
# -> 0
```

As in most debugging situations, the thing to do is *divide and conquer.*  Do the simplest thing which actually does work and then gradually make it look like your problem, or make your problem look like it.

In this case, you could capture the output in a file (or do what @chepner suggests and pipe it through `od`) and examine it in detail, looking for e.g. tab characters; alternatively, you could try commands whose output is even simpler than your `df`.

Comment: There are 4 trailing spaces I missed out. It's is now working. Thanks all.